# Some keys not working

Tags: keyboard

Suddenly both of my CTRL keys, Windows key and the Enter key at the Num Lock has stopped working. I used a different keyboard and the keys worked fine. Does this mean the fault is on the keyboard itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It surely looks like your keyboard has a problem.

You could try to clean it beneath the keys (very carefully), or have it replaced,
or just continue with the other keyboard.